# Passing a String Array to a Function

Tags: c++

I have a couple of string arrays in C++ that are defined as const strings

```
const string ABC[5] = {“1”,”2”,”3”,”4”,”5”};
const string DEF[3] = {“1”,”2”,”3”};
```

I need to pass each of them to the same function similar to this pseudo code:

```
void doSomething(string strArray[])
{
    // loop to access all strings in the array and do something .
};
```

But when called it gives me an error about type when it is passed to the function

```
doSomethign(ABC);
doSomethign(DEF);
```

This is the error generated

> Error C2664   'void roster::strInput1(std::string [])': cannot convert
>   argument 1 from 'const std::string [5]' to 'std::string []'

I have tried to use the const type as well but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Error C2664 'void roster::strInput1(std::string [])': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const std::string [5]' to 'std::string []'

Comment: Consider using a `std::vector` or a `std::array`.

Comment: `void doSomething(const string strArray[])` works for me.

Comment: I would love to use vector as it makes sense to do that but it is a requirement for a class project that the data be input using const string[]

Comment: @vcp when I tired that the passed array is empty even though it is populated before.

Comment: You code has two issues (presumably typos): curly quotation marks (`“` and `”`) instead of straight quotation mark `"`; and `doSomethign` and `doSomething` are different functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ABC` and `DEF` when passed as parameters decay to a pointer of type `const string*` which is not compatible with the type of `strArray[]`.

Moreover, if you want to loop through the arrays inside the `doSomething` function, you will also need to pass the size of the arrays so as to know the bounds of the arrays.
Since the sizes of `ABC` and `DEF` are different, what you need to use here is a function template.

Here is an example to loop through an array of `T` and print the elements.

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
void doSomething(T (&arr)[N])
{
    // loop to access all elements in the array and print them.
    for(auto const& var: arr)
        cout << var << '\n';
}
```

See [Demo here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/48e66bb065ef4619).

If it is just a `std::string` array, you can just parameterize over the non-type parameter `N` which is the size of the array. The function template in this case will just be:

```
template<size_t N>
void doSomething(const std::string (&arr)[N])
{
    // loop to access all strings in the array and do something .
    for(auto const& str: arr)
        cout << str << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I didn't think about this way its been a good 10 years since ive touched c++ but have started a class thanks for the help!

Comment: ABC ain't a pointer, it decays to a pointer. It's a `const std::string[]`

Comment: As the OP does not mention any other type than `std::string` in his question, I think it could be valuable to include also an example where you do no parameterize over the type `T` in the function template `doSomething(...)`, but only over the non-type parameter `N`. Readers unfamiliar with (function) templates might think they _must_ include the type parameterization for this (idiomatic) approach to work.

Comment: @dfri: Updated as per your comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the use of C-style arrays, I rather see `std::array` or `std::vector`. The 2 main issues with this are the loss of size-information and the decay to pointer behavior.
 That said, your underlying problem is const correctness.

For the purpose of simplicity, I'll rewrite your code to the equivalent based on std::vector next to the C-style variants. Please see the answer of P.W for why size information is important and how to deal with it. My answer is more focused on not introducing a templated method that requires you to expose the algorithm.

The following code defines a constant vector of strings. Once defined const, this should not change by the one receiving this object. (Ignoring mutable and const_cast).

```
const std::vector<std::string> ABC = {"1","2","3","4","5"};
const std::string ABC[] = {"1","2","3","4","5"};
```

As this object is created as const, it can never change and const_cast is undefined behavior. Mutable ain't used in `std::string`, so no internal state can change.

So what's happening with your function?

```
void doSomething(std::vector<std::string> &strArray);
void doSomething(std::string strArray[], size_t size);
```

This signature accepts a non-const vector of strings. Passing a const object to this function ain't allowed as this function signature allows modifications to the original instance.

So, how to fix: correct the signature to not allow any modifications. This is preferred if one doesn't modify its input arguments.

```
void doSomething(const std::vector<std::string> &strArray);
void doSomething(const std::string strArray[], size_t size);
```

Or if you need modifications, remove the const at creation:

```
 std::vector<std::string> ABC = {"1","2","3","4","5"};
 std::string ABC[] = {"1","2","3","4","5"};
```

As I've used std::vector instead of C-style arrays, we even get a third possibility that ain't possibles with the C-style arrays: pass by value.

```
void doSomething(std::vector<std::string> strArray)
```

In this case, the function gets a copy of the data. This could be useful if one has to do some manipulations to the vector without influencing the caller. For example: Convert all strings to upper case or sort the vector.

Comment: I think it's good that you expand also in this direction, but _"So, how to fix: correct the signature to not allow any modifications: (preferred)"_ can be misleading. The idiomatic approach here would be to pass the array by reference, parameterizing over the size of the array as a non-type template parameter in a function template. With the approach above, the array to pointer decay will mean size information is lost in `doSomething` - how would we e.g. safely loop over the contents of the array argument (of different arrays sizes) when we only have a pointer in the body of `doSomething`?

Comment: ... so +1 from me if you keep the `const` discussion, but consider mentioning the drawbacks/dangers of trying to write a size-agnostic function by simply stripping away the size information by means of array to pointer decay (and thus, loss of size).

Comment: @drfi: I didn't do that, assuming the C-arrays where a result of 'school education', I've rewrote the code with std::vector and the C-arrays (with size). The answer of P.W is more focussed on this size aspect and resolves the const-ness problem implicitly as the T-template-param takes this over.

Answer (score -1):

if you are passing const array try to write it in function too and put star instead of  brackets.

```
void doSomething(const string *strArray)
{
// loop to access all strings in the array and do something .
};
```

Comment: your answer might solve the problem, though it doesn't explain why this is a right way of solving it. (Ps: I'm not responsible for the down vote)